# How to merge raster classes using the raster calculator?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, merge, reclassify

I need to do an analysis on landscape change for which agriculture is involved. In my raster they are defined as six different classes which is not relevant for my research I was wondering if you can merge these classes into one using the raster calculator while maintaining all other classes. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following raster calculator expression reclassifies the raster:

```
 if ( "my_raster@1" <= 6, 1,"my_raster@1")
```

all values <= 6 will have the value 1, the others remain unchanged

Comment: Thanks eurojam, this perfectly did the trick! One remaining question though, it does "shift" the value of the other numbers right? So in these case, value X that was 15, will be 10 now no?

Comment: no it does not shift the other numbers, the condition in the if clause says: if the number is lower or equal 6, then shift it to 1, else leave it as it is...

Comment: Ah perfect, it's exactly what I have been looking for, thanks!